# Cannot convert from varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make this query work but all the time it gives:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've trying make a cast like it show in the code I do not know what else to do

In line 20 there's another idea I had but didn't work either.

```sql
SELECT 'Programadas', COUNT(*)
    FROM [Base100].[dbo].[HIST_MOVIMIENTO_ENCA] enca
        INNER JOIN EHC_FORMATO FORMATO ON FORMATO.CodFormato=ENCA.CodFormato
        INNER JOIN [a MEDICO] as medic ON enca.Medico = medic.[número de registro]
        INNER JOIN [ESPECIALIDAD] as espc ON medic.especialidad = espc.codigo
        INNER JOIN EHC_EVENTODEATENCION eve on enca.NoEvento=eve.noevento
        INNER JOIN [a EMPRESA/EPS] eps on eps.nit = eve.empresa
        INNER JOIN H_PACIENTE_HOSPITALIZADO HOSP on HOSP.CodigoHospitalizacion=eve.nohospitalizacion
        INNER JOIN [a PACIENTE] pac ON HOSP.SecuenciaIngreso = pac.[Secuencia Ingreso]
        INNER JOIN H_CAMA C ON HOSP.Habitacion_Cama = C.Habitacion_Cama
        INNER JOIN H_HABITACION HAB ON C.Codigo_Hab = HAB.Codigo_Hab
        INNER JOIN H_CATEGORIA_HAB CHAB ON HAB.Categoria_Hab = CHAB.Codigo_Categoria
        INNER JOIN EHC_ORDENESREALIZADAS ord ON enca.nofolio = ord.nofolio
        INNER JOIN EHC_MOVIMIENTODETA MD on MD.nofolio = enca.NoFolio

        LEFT JOIN [EHC_ORDENESREALIZADAS] ehcord ON enca.NoFolio = ehcord.nofolio

        WHERE FORMATO.CodFormato = 'SPC'
        --AND (SELECT CAST(CONVERT(date, CONVERT (varchar(10), MD.respuesta), 103) as date) FROM EHC_MOVIMIENTODETA MD WHERE MD.nofolio = enca.NoFolio AND MD.CodPregunta = 'SPCA2P1') 
        AND CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING(MD.respuesta, 1,10)) >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) as date)
        AND MD.CodPregunta = 'SPCA2P1'
        AND ord.estado ='P'
        AND ehcord.nofolio is null
```

What I expect it's just the count of the result I know there's no "GROUP BY" but it's ok I just want to know that could be the problem

Comment: Inspect your data, you have some invalid dates in that column - which is why dates should always be stored in a `data` column not a `varchar` column. If your version supports it try [try_convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If not write a query to find the invalid dates.

Comment: You also do not need to cast the date in dateadd, it should be: DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()).

Comment: Show us some example data from md.respuesta

Comment: Usin this query "SELECT MD.respuesta FROM EHC_MOVIMIENTODETA MD WHERE MD.nofolio = 11261637 AND MD.CodPregunta = 'SPCA2P1'" I retive this 17/06/2019 12:00:00 p. m.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data in the table, doing a cast function in your where clause may/will cause some performance issues. May benefit you to look into what SARGABLE is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean. The execution of this requires every single row to be cast/converted to see if it should be filtered so it will not use any indexes. I agree with @DaleBurrell - dates should be stored as dates, which would have also made sure you only have valid dates as values.

Comment: Yeah cheking all the data the problem seems to be in the where I have to recheck everything I'll update when I have something else

Comment: @DaleBurrell, Honestly, i looked at your comment after posting my answer, do you mind my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRY_COVERT` it would return `NULL` without failing the query, so that you can do further investigation on those `null` returned rows:

Example:

```
select 
        TRY_CONVERT (Date, '20190821'), --Success
        TRY_CONVERT (Date, '2019 Aug 21'), --Success
        TRY_CONVERT (Date, '2019 -Aug- 21'), --Success
        TRY_CONVERT (Date, '2019Aug/-21')  -- Failed
```